# jQuery horizontal scroll all the way across the width

Tags: jquery, scroll

In relation to a question I posted on here yesterday, I am trying to get a div which moves horizontally when scrolling, however it only goes so far across (because it's the total window width subtracting the amount scrolled vertically) but I would like this div to go all of the way across the page...how would I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/wH3Fn/

Comment: What have you tried I've seen then last 4 iterations of this fiddle here on SO. And though I understand it is tempting to use SO as a code generation tool.

Comment: I know, I appreciate I have taken the lazy approach, I will do better research next time. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I answered the question yesterday, I'll chime in here, too.

Adding the following to your scroll handler

```
console.log($("#block").css('left'));
```

Shows that the block continues moving after it is out of view. If you need it to move faster (ie if you want it to move across the whole width of the window whilst still in view), then simply multiply up the left value as follows:

```
 $("#block").css({ "left":  (windowWidth - $(window).scrollTop())*2});
```

The edit above makes the block move twice as fast (the *2 multiplier on the end). If you need it to move even faster, use *3 and so on.

As commented on your question, I know it is tempting to use SO as a code generation tool, but this kind of issue is relatively simple to solve yourself with a little logic and some trial and error... You should try to do some research before coming here to ask the question in future, perhaps.

Comment: I apologise, I'm just trying to get to grips with it, I had tried multiplying the scrollTop instead of the whole sum, that is where I was going wrong. I appreciate I have taken the lazy approach, I will do better research next time. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Its fine... I have no problem answering a follow-up question, but from what I understand on SO it seems like its considered poor etiquette. Glad your problem is solved :)